# Don't know where 404 error is coming from

Tags: javascript

Don't know where this 404 error "sites/all/modules/lightbox2/images/blank.gif" is coming from. It's on everypage on www.lostinthesmoke.com. Can't find the reference to it in the page source. I don't know if its Drupal or CloudFlare. CloudFlare says its Drupal or my server. I cleared caches everywhere. I had lightbox2 installed a couple months ago but not on this fresh install. I use this domain to learn and test on. It started showing last night.

Comment: Did you clone the site from a previous one?

Comment: no, I just started a new ec2 and downloaded drupal through drush about a week ago. i starting to think its cloudflare when i access my site through my ec2 ip, http://23.23.95.194/ i don't get the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go into inspector, you can see:

```
<object data="http://www.lostinthesmoke.com/sites/all/modules/lightbox2/images/blank.gif" width="0" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; "></object>
```

is being added at the very bottom of your page.  Why?  I dunno, but it's there :)  The fact that it doesn't show up in "view source" suggests it's being added via javascript on page load.

Why isn't it finding blank.gif?  Again, I dunno.  It's here in my lightbox2 directory, so, perhaps your installation has been corrupted and thinks it is still installed.

Comment: Jimajamma, Thanks for the advice it helped. Justin from CloudFlare found the issue, it had something to do with their preloader feature.

Comment: quite welcome, glad I could poke around and help out.

Comment: Sometimes ftp corrupts images